# Deploying typedoc to gh-pages

Tags: node.js, typescript, travis-ci, github-pages, typedoc

I created [this repository](https://github.com/fireflysemantics/is) and I'm trying to deploy the typedoc directory `doc` that is generated in the root folder to github pages so that I can provide a link to the typedoc.

I looks like it is working according to the raw build log:

https://api.travis-ci.org/v3/job/398886309/log.txt

And it does have the readme page deployed:

https://fireflysemantics.github.io/is/

But the doc folder generated by typedoc is not accessible:

https://fireflysemantics.github.io/is/doc

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Posted an answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51180920/gh-pages-content-not-rendering-at-corresponding-url).  Travis is deploying to `gh-pages` correctly, but the publishing source has to be set to `gh-pages` in the repositories settings.