# gh-pages content not rendering at corresponding URL?

Tags: git, github, github-pages

I'm using travis to deploy built content into the projects corresponding `gh-pages` branch.  This is the project:

https://github.com/fireflysemantics/is

I see that the `doc` folder that typedoc generated is in the `gh-pages` branch, however when I go to:

https://fireflysemantics.github.io/is/doc/index.html

I get a 404, but the index.html pages is in the `gh-pages` branch at that location:

https://github.com/fireflysemantics/is/blob/gh-pages/doc/index.html

Any idea why it's not rendering?

Answer (score 1):

OK - Got it.  I had to [configure the publishing source for `gh-pages`](https://help.github.com/articles/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-github-pages/).

Note that for typedoc we also need to add a `.nojekyll` file, so that `gh-pages` does not ignore files staring with `_`.  See my [.travis.yml](https://github.com/fireflysemantics/is/blob/master/.travis.yml) file for how I did this.